# Defining a point to scale from with CSS 2d transforms?

Tags: css, transform

The CSS 2d transforms resize things from the centre of the object being resized - or at least they do in firefox - and I can't find any way to set the direction.

For example,

```
transform:scale(0.5,1);
```

doesn't crush the text by pushing it from the right to the left, it crushes it by going from the left and right to the middle.

JSfiddle showing off what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/two5uh16/

Is there any way to define which direction it should be going? I'm using dynamic content in the form of contenteditable=true, so some hacks mightn't work.

Alternatively, is there any way to change the width of text, as in stretching it?

Comment: Use the property `transform-origin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform-origin: X Y`

In this example the scale will be performed from the top left corner:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/two5uh16/1/)

```
#scale1{
    background:#FF0000;
    transform:scale(0.5,1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```css
#scale1{
    background:#FF0000;
    transform:scale(0.5,1);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}
#scale2{
    background:#0000FF;
    transform:scale(2,1);
    
}
```

```html
<p>This is where the edge is</p>
<div id="scale1">Hello</div>
<div id="scale2">Bye</div>
```